# javac: command not found - after installing Java

Tags: java

I just followed the mentioned steps of installing `java` on `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS` from article [How do I install Java on Ubuntu](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-do-I-install-Java-on-Ubuntu) .

But it looks like some software is missing here because when I run the following command:

```shell
javac -version
```

It says `javac is not installed!`

I installed `java` using the following command:

```shell
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre
```

Comment: Look at the info on this site. You may be running an EOL non supported version of the app https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/ssf228/clarification_of_openjdk_8_end_of_life/ You should also read the info at this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to install the `jdk`. Install it using the following command:

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```

Comment: JDK 8 is now officially unsupported. please do not use such kinds of releases.

Comment: @RishonJR Atleast you could tell which versions are supported... I think people like you are more interested in down voting others answers and questions not in providing actual solution.

Comment: The supported version are JDK 17 and JDK 19.